# PHP access variable outside of class

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller

I have a signup building in mvc structure,

1st: pass data into **signup controller**, **Controller** require **model** and **connect db**

2nd: pass those data into **model** again...

```
class signup extend Controller(){
    public function __construct($id, $email){
        $this->model('signup_model'); //include model (Controller's method)

        $signup = new signup_model;
        $row = $signup->check($id, $email);
    }

}

if(isset($_POST...)){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

   $controller = signup($id, $email);
   .....
}
```

My problem is in my form, i have many data need to pass into model and I have to pass those data again and again (controller, model)

```
$controller = signup($id, $email...); //many data have to pass into class
```

Is any better way to pass data into model without parameter?

Comment: btw, process the request and retrieve your inputs sound like a work to do in your controller. I'm not sure why you do that outside it

Comment: so should i put isset... inside of controller class?